# Activity layout inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, visual-inheritance

I start develop application on Android!
I need to show common control on the top of few screens.
In Blackberry I just inherit my screens from base screen with needed controls and it inherit UI and behaviour from base type.

How can i do similar thing in Android? I mean, how can i organize it?
Maybe, i need to create control or layout, which i can use on my screens?
Or i need inherit one activity from another and use addContentView()?

What opportunities are there and what advantages / disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [`<include>` XML layout directive](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Comment: Thanx! But what with behaviour? Can I create my own 
"Control" with button with MessageBox, for example, and include this "Control" in my screens?

Comment: You can create custom `View` classes if you wish. That is a somewhat complex topic, beyond the scope of a StackOverflow comment. FWIW, here is a project with a sample custom `View`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Views/ColorMixer/